# How to retrieve the order id of an order in drupal commerce?

Tags: commerce

Is there a way to do it from the tpl?

ie: **page--admin--commerce--orders.tpl.php**

I've tried this, but naturally, I get an undefined **$order_id** variable

```
if (commerce_order_load($order_id)) {
  echo $order->uid;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for the order ID related to the current cart you can use [`commerce_cart_order_id()`](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_order_id/DC):

```
$order = commerce_order_load(commerce_cart_order_id());
```

But you shouldn't use it directly in a template file. Use a preprocess hook instead, it's better all round.

Comment: Thanks! How to know what preprocessors to use with drupal commerce? (http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/DC)?

Comment: I mean, in order to get to: moduleName_preprocess_hook what is the hook I'm after? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It would just be `hook_preprocess_page()`, you can check `request_uri()` against whatever URL (admin/commerce/orders maybe?) to check you're on the right page